# How to update data in share intent?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, share

I have a global variable. During the work of the app it changes the value. There is a share button and when I tap it I can share only the value when the app started. I want to send by shareIntent the updated value. How to do it?

```
private int counter;
...
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    counterTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counter_text_view);
    counter++;
    String counterStr = Integer.toString(counter);
    counterTextView.setText(counterStr);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate menu resource file.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    // Locate MenuItem with ShareActionProvider
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);

    // Fetch and store ShareActionProvider
    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(item);
    setShareIntent(createShareIntent());

    // Return true to display menu
    return true;

}

// Call to update the share intent
private void setShareIntent(Intent shareIntent) {
    if (mShareActionProvider != null) {
        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
    }
}
private Intent createShareIntent() {
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
            counter);
    return shareIntent;
}
```

Comment: Make the variable static?

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work. I have tried it...

Answer (score 1):

You may use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to store your data permanently.

Comment: I store data with SharedPreferences. I need to put updated value from counter to shareIntent!!!

Comment: Please add more code to it, we really don't know what exactly you trying to achive. Where you update your counter?

Comment: I added the code. I update counter, but the share intent send the counter value from the start and not a update value.

Answer (score 0):

You are putting a constant text string "counter" into the `Intent`. Maybe try something like this instead:

```
shareIntent.putExtra("counter", counter);
```

and get it back out like this:

```
int counter = getIntent().getIntExtra("counter", -1);
if (counter != -1) {
    // do stuff
}
```